# Android NDK project : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: java, android, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am a newbie with the NDK.

I want to add some C++ code to my standard java Android Studio project.

What I did:

1. add cpp folder under main folder
2. add myccplib.cpp and myccplib.h in my cpp folder
3. add the following in Gradle (module):

   ```
   android { 

    externalNativeBuild {

            cmake {

                version "3.10.2"
            } 
    } 
    }
   ```
4. code in myccplib.cpp :

   ```
   #include "myccplib.h"


    #include <jni.h>
    #include <string>

    extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL


    Java_com_example_tof_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */) {
        std::string hello = "Hello, World!";
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
   ```
5. Code in MainActivity.java:

> 

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myccplib"); // "myjni.dll" in Windows, "libmyjni.so" in Unixes
    }


    public native String stringFromJNI();


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String s = stringFromJNI();
        Log.d("stringFromJNI " + s);



}

}
```

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Problem: I get the crash:

```
2020-10-14 19:02:45.465 25918-25918/com.example.tof E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tof, PID: 25918
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.tof-t8Csh416BSdO6UBfZv0mOw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.tof-t8Csh416BSdO6UBfZv0mOw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmyccplib.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
    at com.example.tof.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:37)
```

I use Android 4.0.

Anybody can tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't seem to match the stacktrace. The stacktrace says that `liblibmyccplib.so` can't be found, which suggests that you mistakenly included the `"lib"` prefix in your `loadLibrary` call (i.e. that you're actually doing `System.loadLibrary("libmyccplib");`)

Comment: Can you share the contents of your CMakeLists.txt? Make sure the library name used in System.loadLibrary matches the one specified in target_link_libraries within CMakeLists.txt. If is your first project, instead of adding everything manually you could use Android Studios's "Native C++" wizard project template, so you may use it as reference to learn the basics.

Comment: @PerracoLabs Thanks! I don't have any CMakeLists.txt :) I see that I should put it in the cpp folder. But what should I write in this file ? By the way Michael I corrected the crash log ; I didn't paste the correct version. Thanks !!!

Comment: @Regis_AG If you don't have any native build script file, so neither CMakeLists.txt nor the old Android.mk, then notice that the native binary will not get compiled. CMakeLists.txt instructs what to compile and generate.I would recommend using the "Native C++" wizard template, so File->New Project->Native C++

Comment: Sorry, actually, I had one but it was empty. Now, I copied and pasted the content of the CMakeLists.txt file of the template C++ project in my project. I renamed the name of the file in CMakeLists.txt. But I still have the issue. Note that it seems that the content of my CMakeLists.txt file is not colorized by Android Studio like in the template project (all characters in gray) ; I don't know if it might have an influence.

Comment: It works !!! So I had two problems : 1) empty CMakeLists.txt file 2) No 'path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt' in Gradle ! Thanks a lot for your great help !!!!